# What should I use to correctly replace deprecated URI.escape

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.7

I need help understanding what is **correct** way to replace deprecated `URI.escape`

```
> URI.escape('space ^%$')
(pry):12: warning: URI.escape is obsolete
=> "space%20%5E%25$
```

Current implementation is this:

```
def escape(*arg)
  warn "URI.escape is obsolete", uplevel: 1
  DEFAULT_PARSER.escape(*arg)
end
```

so, just using `DEFAULT_PARSER` seems to work:

```
> URI::DEFAULT_PARSER.escape('space ^%$')
=> "space%20%5E%25$"
```

but also explicitly stating the parser seems to work as well:

```
> URI::RFC2396_Parser.new.escape('space ^%$')
=> "space%20%5E%25$"
```

What I'm looking for is the context on the Ruby change, so an informed decision could be made.

- why was it deprecated
- why was it moved to RFC2396_Parser? Should we expect new URI parsers?
- are there plans to switch URI::DEFAULT_PARSER?

Comment: [Why was it deprecated](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17309#note-3) [Why it exists in RFC2396_Parser](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17309#note-1)